# Displaying data from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I am making a Node.js & Express app that gets records from a CRM. I'm trying to show the data on a html page by sending the data with:

```
    app.get('/user', (req, res) => {
    let stringify = JSON.stringify(responseObject);
    res.send(stringify);
    });
```

The response I get is:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            keyValues: {},
            keyModified: {}
        }
    ],
    info: {
        perPage: 200,
        count: 1,
        page: 1,
        moreRecords: false,
        keyModified: { }
    },
    keyModified: { }
}
```

I want to display only the data within the "keyValues" object, which contains the data of the user I'm searching for. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract from `responseObject` only the informations that you want to send.
Since `data` is an array you can `map` on it and select only the `keyModified` attribute.
Something like this:

```js
app.get('/user', (req, res) => {
  res.json(responseObject.data.map(d => d.keyModified))
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.